# iOS: Ensure that an image has got no empty area after manual rotation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, area

I have got an UIImageView in which the image can be rotated using UIRotationGestureRecognizer.

Based on the UIImageView a frame in the middle of the screen is extracted from the image.

For the better understanding here's a little screenshot:

http://d.pr/i/hzhA

As you can see there's an empty area at the right edge within the target frame.

The Question is: How can I check if there is an empty area within the target image, for example in the right top area of the target frame (as you can see in the screenshot).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Christian